# Is there a way to know that an Activity was recreated because of a device rotation

Tags: android

I have an activity class that locks itself with a custom PIN whenever it is resumed/recreated (so that I can lend my phone to someone secure in the knowledge they can't see that app's data).

The problem this causes is that rotating the device recreates the Activity and redisplays the PIN lock, which is a bit unsmooth.

So, is there some way the Activity to know either

1. I am being destroyed because of an orientation change.
2. I am being created as a result of an orientation change.

I would like to avoid solutions based on  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` if possible.

**EDIT:** For posterity, I ended up doing this by having all Activities in the app inherit from this [LockableActivity](https://github.com/andrewkreid/mydetic/blob/master/android/MyDetic/app/src/main/java/net/ghosttrails/www/mydetic/LockableActivity.java) class.

Comment: Why would you like to avoid that solution?

Comment: It seems like it's prone to errors, as described here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to check the time passed between 'onPause' and 'onResume'. If it is less than 0.2 seconds then you haven't handed your phone over ...

In fact, you could make this a user controllable security feature: how long away from the activity before pin entry is needed again could be set by the user.

For the truly obsessive, you could ask the user to reorient their phone during the set up phase to determine the associated time lapse and set that as the minimum.

As noted elsewhere, you could also use onSaveInstanceState. In this approach that is when you would store the time for comparison later.

Comment: I like this idea. Rather that try and treat rotation as a special case, just make it so the pin lock only appears if the time between pause and resume of any of the app's activities is greater than n seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in your activity, it will get triggered when the device is rotated

```
 @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    //perform your operations here

        }
```

If you also want to check whether it is in landscape or portrait mode , you can apply below conditions

```
     if(newConfig.orientation  == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){



        }
else {


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is normally destroyed, `onSaveInstanceState()` will never be called. During orientation change (or any other change that needs to load different resources), `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called. In this method, you can save your data that you want your activity to have during it's re-creation.

If your activity is normally created, `savedInstanceState` will be `null`. But if it was created because of re-creation (like change in orientation), then `savedInstanceState` will not be null and you can use this to fetch the data that you saved during `onSaveInstanceState()`.

It's a bad idea to override `onConfigurationChanged()`, instead you could just use these methods that Android provide to persist your data or application logic . In your case, it could be something like this in your `onCreate()`.

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
       boolean loggedIn= savedInstanceState.getBoolean("LoggedIn",false);
       if(!loggedIn){
            // Not logged in, hence show pinlock
        }
 }
```

You could do something like this.

Comment: Rotation is not the only situation in which onSavedInstanceState is called and the information is retained. The docs are very loose about exactly when you can and can't rely on it for this kind of thing. You will need additional checks.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my answer, orientation change alone is not responsible for calling `onSaveInstanceState()`. Even going into `CarMode` will recreate the activity. It's called when activity is recreated because 'activity might need to load alternative resources'. You can't rely on this method when android OS kills your activity due to memory constraint, but it the activity is in the foreground and you activity gets recreated because of orientation change, this method gets called all the time.